# execute python file- No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, ssh, shellexecute

I try to execute python file through the terminal with ssh (the file itself is not in my computer).

I do the following:

```
./playg.py
```

and I get:
": No such file or directory"

I am in the right directory for sure (when I write cat `playg.py` I can see the content of the file|

The file has the r/w/x properties:
-r-xr-xr-x

Comment: try with "python playg.py"

Comment: [To execute your python script without python word prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587877/run-a-python-script-in-terminal-without-the-python-command)

Answer (score 1):

First go to `playg.py` existing folder.

Then type `python playg.py`

Answer (score 1):

You can execute it with python playg.py.

The reason you might not be able to execute it with ./playg.py is the first line of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or similar in the first line might not be appropriate for the system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

would look for the python executable in the current environment and is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

check for endline characters encoding. if you have cr-lf encoding instead of lf it gives that error...

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory containing the file and run:

```
python play.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding **python**  before the file name while trying to execute

```
    python playg.py
```

Answer (score 0):

python /path/to/file/playg.py should work